# What word would you use to describe a craft person?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there such a word as Craftor or Crafter?
I am creating a poster for a craft show. I want to say, Crafters and Vendors needed, but I don't think Crafter is a word.

Comment: How about _craftspeople_ and/or _artisans_?

Comment: I'd be willing to say in that specific context, "Crafter" would be understood and would be fine to use.

Comment: @BruceWayne agreed - crafter is common.  [See also the "other words" section under "craft" in Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crafter#other-words).   (FWIW, I've never seen "craftor" and though I'd understand it, I would assume it was a typo)

Comment: Agree with @KarlG about _artisans_. That seems to be the trending term these days.

Comment: In the context of the question, there's a false premise that *crafter* is not a word. So, it should be the answer if it was only rejected on the basis of it not existing. Otherwise, I agree with the comment about *artisan*. That's the word I would personally use. But it's not clear if, given the validity of *crafter*, an alternate is still being asked for. So, I won't provide it as an actual answer.

Comment: I like *artisan*.  It tells me right away you do BS for a living.

Comment: A modicum of research can determine [if a word exists](https://www.onelook.com/?w=Crafter&ls=a)

Answer (score 11):

> 2007   R. W. Hesse Jewelry Making through History: To make brass
>   jewelry, **crafters** use a variety of tools, including..buffing
>   wheels, rouge polish, [etc.].

**crafter**  [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/crafter) and [crafter](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/crafters):

> noun a person who does craftwork

Crafter(s) is an English word, of the less frequently used category.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The noun form of *to craft* which is most often used is [*craftsman*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/craftsman), plural *craftsmen*. If you're worried that you're excluding women, consider using the gender-neutral form [*craftsperson*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/craftsperson). 'Crafter' *can* be used (Merriam Webster lists it as a synonym of 'craftsman') but is much less common; see [this Google Ngram Viewer graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crafter%2Ccraftsman%2Ccraftswoman%2Ccraftsperson&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrafter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccraftsman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccraftswoman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccraftsperson%3B%2Cc0) comparing the frequency of *craftsman*, *craftsperson*, *crafter* and *craftswoman*.

[image]

Comment: I'd be careful with this one - craftsmen are (as your dictionary link says) generally practitioners of a given trade, i.e. professionals.  If OP wants to only recruit people working in a trade then this will be fine, but if OP wants anyone who has ever done some arts-and-crafts time, then this is likely to exclude them (or at least be unclear to folks reading the poster).

Answer (score 2):

What do you think of the term **craft artists** (the word [**artist**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/artist) is a term in English commonly used to mean *a person skilled at a particular task or occupation*)? What I found out is that some companies out there do use this term in their job descriptions when they hire people. Here's how the job search website *Sokanu.com* describes this type of occupation on [one of their pages](https://www.sokanu.com/careers/craft-artist/):

> **A craft artist** is someone who uses a variety of materials and techniques to create art for sale and exhibition. They create handmade objects such as pottery, glassware, textiles, or other objects that are usually designed to be functional, but sometimes the original works of art have only aesthetic value rather than a functional one.